# How to select single value in a column in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, html-lists

Here is the for loop displaying numbers.

```
   <ul class="number-list" id="tblBlah">
    @for (int i = 1; i <= 90; i++)
    {
    <li id=@(item.GameDay.Id +"_"+ i) class="">@i</li>  
 }
</ul>
```

and it displays output like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plIjZ.png)

Now I want to select a single value at a time in each column and display the selected value at the bottom. I am looking for a solution in JavaScript. 
*Please do look at the attached picture for reference.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're providing an `id` to each element. You can use `getElementById` to select the appropriate item.

For instance, if you'd like to select the item with `id` equal to `4`.

```
document.getElementById(item.GameDay.Id + '_4')
```

Comment: didn't work out. Can you please help me out as i want to select only one value in a single column.

Comment: I had to guess as to what you were setting as ids. What issue are you running into when trying to get the ID? Ensure you're using the right ID.

Comment: sir kindly take a look at picture, i want to select only one number per column.

Comment: That is understood, but I need to know what issues you are running into when you try the above code. This should select one item by it's ID.